# I got the error code trying to install django

Tags: python, django, windows, pip, stack-overflow

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
yield
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 519, in read
data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
data = self.__fp.read(amt)
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 465, in read
s = self.fp.read(amt)
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 705, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1273, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1129, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
return func(self, options, args)
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 472, in resolve
state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
if not criterion.candidates:
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in **bool**
return bool(self._sequence)
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 140, in **bool**
return any(self)
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 128, in 
return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 32, in _iter_built
candidate = func()
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 204, in _make_candidate_from_link
self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 295, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in **init**
self.dist = self._prepare()
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 227, in _prepare
dist = self._prepare_distribution()
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 305, in _prepare_distribution
return self._factory.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 508, in prepare_linked_requirement
return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 550, in _prepare_linked_requirement
local_file = unpack_url(
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 239, in unpack_url
file = get_http_url(
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 102, in get_http_url
from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\network\download.py", line 145, in **call**
for chunk in chunks:
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 144, in iter
for x in it:
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
for chunk in response.raw.stream(
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 576, in stream
data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 512, in read
with self._error_catcher():
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 153, in **exit**
self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
File "C:\Users\HP\myproject\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.

Comment: Please post codes in code format. Also indicate the codes or CLI commands that rendered such error.

Answer (score 0):

Test the Django installation in a virtual environment,
in cmd:

```
> python -m venv env
> cd env/Scripts/activate
> pip install django
```